# How can I highlight the top menu item when I'm on a post in a subcategory?

Tags: wordpress, menu, highlight

On my website you can see only a single depth of menu. But the structure in menu administration is:

```
- Home (page)
- About
- Magazine (category)
  + News (category)
    -> Post
    -> ..
       .. 
    -> Post
```

And when I'm on the "Post" page, in the "News" category, I want the top-menu item "Magazine" to be highlighted. WordPress does this only in menus a single level deep.